# Postfix: Allow a certain sender only from a certain IP address

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a client who authenticates with SASL, and they keep getting their password stolen. Their legitimate mail is sent from one IP address, so I'd like to block all mail sent from their email unless it comes from that IP. Is this possible? I've tried to find a solution but I'm fairly new to postfix and inherited this setup. I can see how to do one or the other but not how to combine them without affecting other users. We're using postfix with amavis as content filter. Thank you.

Edited to add things I've tried: I created a local.cf rule for amavis/spamassassin, like this:

```
header __LOCAL_FROM_USER  From =~ /me\@domain\.com/i
header __LOCAL_IP_USER    Received =~ /11.22.33.44/
meta LOCAL_EMPIRE_RULE  (__LOCAL_FROM_USER && !__LOCAL_IP_USER)
score  LOCAL_EMPIRE_RULE 20.0
```

However, that doesn't work because the originating IP isn't in the Received headers. I guess that's due to the way it's passed through from postfix to amavis. So that blocks all mail from their address, even if it's from their IP.

So I tried adding their IP to mynetworks in postfix's main.cf. I'd be satisfied short-term with relaying all email from their IP and blocking everything from their address otherwise. I can't seem to stop it from getting spam filtered, though, even though I have this in amavisd.conf:

```
$policy_bank{'MYNETS'} = {   # mail originating from @mynetworks
  originating => 1,  # is true in MYNETS by default, but let's make it explicit
  os_fingerprint_method => undef,  # don't query p0f for internal clients
};
```

Comment: Have you looked at policyd? https://wiki.policyd.org/

Comment: Not yet. I was hoping to find a solution within postfix/amavis.